# Flask-Security error "User object has no attribute roles'

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-security

This is my first time using Flask-Security, and I can't seem to successfully create a user.

Every time I try, I get a "User object has no attribute roles" error.

Here is the relevant code:
https://gist.github.com/ianseyer/f08d3f47471588e79022

**EDIT:**
Realized it might be because i didn't not have `__tablename__ = 'roles'`, but that gives me this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child     tables on relationship User.role.  Specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.  If 'secondary' is     present, 'secondaryjoin' is needed as well.
```

Answer (score 1):

You've called it `role`. Change

```
role = db.relationship('Role', secondary=roles_users, backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))
```

to

```
roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary=roles_users, backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))
```